# Prime factorization with superscript exponents java

Tags: java, algorithm, exponent, superscript, factorization

I would like to have my outputs from my Prime Factorization module in my calculator program to be in this form:  247500 = 2² · 3² · 5⁴ · 11 instead of 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^4 * 11 or 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11.

The problem is that due to my extremely limited programming knowledge, my implementation of exponent sorting and displaying slows my program down "exponentially" (pun intended) for larger numbers.  I have tried to find a more efficient way of doing the operation, but cannot find any other way.

I devised the following method...it works, but its very slow.  I apologize if conventions are not being followed (I am a learner programmer).

The prime numbers are stored in the array FACTOR[c]...I'm using BigInteger in my factorization module.

```
if (counter == 0) {
                            
  OUTPUT = "prime number";
                            
}
                        
else {
                            
  OUTPUT = OUTPUT + FACTOR[c];
  c ++;
                            
  do {
                                
     if (FACTOR[c].compareTo(FACTOR[c-1]) == 0) {
                                    
       exponent++;
                                    
       if (c == counter) {  // condition if the number with exponent is the last in derivation.
                                        
      exp = String.valueOf(exponent);
      str.conversion (exp);
                                        
      OUTPUT = OUTPUT + exp;
      break;
                                        
       }
                                    
     }
                            
     else if (((FACTOR[c].compareTo(FACTOR[c-1]) == 1 || (FACTOR[c].compareTo(FACTOR[c-1]) ==  -1))&& exponent > 1)) {
    
       if (c == counter) {  // condition if the number with exponent is the last in derivation.
                                        
         exp = String.valueOf(exponent);
         str.conversion (exp);
                                        
         OUTPUT = OUTPUT + exp + " · " + FACTOR[c];
                                        
         break;
                                        
       }
                                    
       exp = String.valueOf(exponent);
       str.conversion (exp);
                                    
       OUTPUT = OUTPUT + exp + " · " + FACTOR[c];
                                    
       exponent = 1;
                                
    }
                            
    else if (((FACTOR[c].compareTo(FACTOR[c-1]) == 1 || (FACTOR[c].compareTo(FACTOR[c-1]) == -1)) && exponent == 1)) {
                                    
     OUTPUT = OUTPUT + " · " + String.valueOf(FACTOR[c]);
                                
     }
                            
     c++;
                                
  } while (c!= counter+1);
                            
}
                        
answer = firstword + " = " + OUTPUT;

class Convtonum {
    
    void conversion (String str) {
        
            // Converts 0-9 numbers into superscript form
            str = str.replaceAll("0", "\u2070");
        str = str.replaceAll("1", "\u00b9");
        str = str.replaceAll("2", "\u00b2");
        str = str.replaceAll("3", "\u00b3");
        str = str.replaceAll("4", "\u2074");
        str = str.replaceAll("5", "\u2075");
        str = str.replaceAll("6", "\u2076");
        str = str.replaceAll("7", "\u2077");
        str = str.replaceAll("8", "\u2078");
        str = str.replaceAll("9", "\u2079");       

        CALCULATOR.exp = str;
        
    }

}
```

How could this be made to be more faster / efficient?

Comment: How large is this program? You might want to consider adding more of your code to this post. How long does it take to calculate the factorization for each prime number? Or how long does the entire program take to run?

Comment: Which is your question? Are you asking how to get output with superscript exponents, as opposed to plain text only? Or are you asking for with a prime factorization algorithm?  (As far as I can tell, it seems to be the latter.)  If you are asking about both, you risk having the question closed for lack of focus. If you are asking about one, inclusion of details about the other risks having the question closed, also for lack of focus. Please provide a [Complete but Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that focuses on *one* issue.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It may help to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  The question should show example input, expected output / behavior, and actual output / behavior. Eliminate details not relevant to the problem.

Comment: @old dog programmer...thanks for your reply.   I believed I have made it clear in my question that my problem is specific to improving the efficiency of my output module (which outputs the prime factorization using exponents in superscript form).    I am not in need of a prime factorization algorithm...these are in abundance.   The specific issue is how to convert the output 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 to 2² · 3² · 5⁴ using a faster method than the one I have been using.  Thank you.

Comment: @Anon...there is no other relevant code, only the prime factorization module which can be via use of trial division or Lenstra elliptic-curve, but this is not an issue.  The specific issue is with converting the output 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 to  2² · 3² · 5⁴  using an efficient method rather than the clunky one I have used.

Comment: @ Old Dog Programmer...I do sincerely apologize for that.  I am a learner programmer.  I do not believe that my code is out of context for what precedes my output module is just the prime factorization algorithm itself (which I do not need to post).  My problem is specific in how to convert 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 (prime number in FACTOR[c] array) to 2² · 3² · 5⁴ in a faster, more efficient manner.

Comment: @ Old Dog Programmer...you could add any prime factorization algorithm which outputs the primes in an array, then just cut and paste my output module to process the array.  I did not believe that I needed to do anything else to explain the issue.  As I have stated, I am a learner programmer...

Comment: It is good program design to have the calculations and output in separate methods.  `... public BigInteger [] factorize (long num) { ... } ... public String toStringWithExponents (BigInteger [] factors) { ... } ... `  Then, a third method to get the number to be factorized, and call the other two.  That will make it better for you, and better for us when you ask a question here. You can provide us with a minimal reproducible example by putting `2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11`,  and possibly other examples, into arrays to show us a minimal reproducible example that concentrates on the problem.

Comment: @Old Dog Prg.  Yeah, but I do not believe it changes anything in regards to whether one method or several methods are in play here.  My output module receives an array (FACTOR[c[), and I gave an example of an output (2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11).  The issue is how to process this array to output 2² · 3² · 5⁴  using a faster method than the one I have devised.  I don't believe anything I have posted is out of context or insufficient in detailing the problem, and assistance has been given (which I will carefully study in due course).  I do not understand the, for want of better words, antagonism here!

Comment: @trincot...the reason I did not react was because someone else (thorin9000) gave the correct solution to the matter.  He gave his solution in the comments section, rather than giving a formal answer.  The answer provided by gOOse was not the optimal solution because it required me to rewrite my entire program, whilst thorin9000's answer enabled me to make a few simple modifications to my code enabling my program to function correctly.  I thanked thorin9000 for his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful to show more of your code in an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

One specific problem is that you try to replace a digit with the `unicode` value whether that digit is present or not.  There may be better solutions than the following but this processes the digits in the exponent as `ints` and limits the string handling.

Store the symbols in a list, in order of their index.

```
static List<String> sups = List.of("\u2070", "\u00b9", "\u00b2", "\u00b3",
        "\u2074", "\u2075", "\u2076", "\u2077", "\u2078", "\u2079");
```

Now define a lambda to call to convert to the exponent.

- first, covert to positive and save sign if required
- then, iterate over the number, getting each digit using the remainder `%` operator. Then using that digit, index into the list of unicode characters and prepend the digit, building the exponent from right to left.
- then prepend the sign and return the string.

```
Function<Integer, String> toExp = exp -> {
    String sign = "";
    if (exp < 0) {
        sign = "\u207B"; // minus sign
        exp = -exp;
    }
    String result = sups.get(exp % 10);
    while (exp > 10) {
        exp /= 10;
        result = sups.get(exp % 10) + result;
    }
    return sign + result;
};

System.out.printf("%d%s%n", 3, toExp.apply(12));
System.out.printf("%d%s%n", 12, toExp.apply(-329));
```

prints

```
3¹²
12⁻³²⁹
```

Comment: @WJS...thanks for your response. I do not believe that there is any other relevant code to post, for what precedes my output module is just the prime factorization module itself which stores 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 primes in an array to be processed by my output module (conversion to 2² · 3² · 5⁴).  I will carefully study what you have suggested and will try to implement the changes in my program, thank you.

Comment: @WJS...certainly, I do apologize.  I have been answering several "comments" on this post.  Many thanks again for the time and trouble you have taken with this.

Comment: It is worth noting that the time taken to format the factorization is *probably* going to be tiny compared with the time taken to do the factorization.  Even if you do the formatting inefficiently.  (Or to put it another way ... I suspect that you have jumped to an incorrect conclusion as to why your complete program is slow.)

Comment: And if you want to understand why factorization is slow ("exponentially" as you put it), read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization.  It points out that no polynomial time algorithm has yet been discovered (or more precisely, published in open literature) for integer factorization.

Comment: @Stephen....I have several different prime factorization algorithms which output the prime numbers in an array (trial division, eliptic curve etc).  The method I use to convert 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 to 2² · 3² · 5⁴ does slow things down for larger numbers.  As I have stated several times, it is not the prime factorization algorithm that is the issue here, it is how I get the output in the  2² · 3² · 5⁴ form.  Many here do not seem to understand this simple point...

Comment: @ Stephen C...again, it is respectfully your lack of understanding of my question.  My issue is specific in the getting an output in the form 2² · 3² · 5⁴.  You did not understand my post, simple as.

Comment: @StephenC You are correct about factorization in general as it is a mathematically intensive operation.  My focus was on the formatting question and sped up the exponent conversion by a factor of about `60-70` based on simple iterative tests using `System.nanotime()`.

Comment: I surely >did< understand your question.  But with respect, you did not understand >my< point. So I will say it again.  Yoiu said (and I quote): *"I have tried to find a more efficient way of doing the operation, but cannot find any other way."* - The efficiency of the operation of formatting the output is close to IRRELEVANT to the overall application performance.  There is no point in optimizing code that has minimal impact on the overall performance.  It makes no difference if the application can output the result in 0.01 seconds if it takes 1 seconds or 1,000 to do the factorization.

Comment: Also ... as a learner programmer ... you should be paying attention to what people are trying to teach you.  And not >assuming<  that they don't know what they are talking about.  One lesson you need to learn is to be wary of premature optimization; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize.

Comment: @WJS...indeed, this is exactly the whole purpose of my original post!!!!  I do not understand why many here did not get this.  I had requests for more code (what more code could I provide?  Which factorization algorithm should I have put in (eliptic curve, trial division...its completely irrelevant to the matter because I used the same output module for all of them).  I thought it best to put in the section of code that was the issue...I gave an example of the formatting I wanted (2² · 3² · 5⁴), said I had numbers in an array (FACTOR[c] which had the prime numbers.  What more was needed?!

Comment: @Stephen...go to my original post and highlight where I was asking for assistance with prime factorization algorithms?  You cannot...the matter was purely about the formatting issue.  Secondly, you have not tried my output module with any prime factorization algorithm...it does impact it significantly as opposed to having just the output in the form of 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11.  My code which converts the 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 output to 2² · 3² · 5⁴ incurs a lot computation cost for larger composites.  You clearly do not understand the issue here...

Comment: @ThomasFarkas  The issue is that without knowing how you are factoring the values, the issue may be (and probably is) in the factoring process, not in the formatting process.  In general, factoring is very computationally intensive. Formatting, isn't,.  Stephen is correct in pointing out that you may be focusing on something that adds little to no performance improvement relative to the factoring algorithm. 1/2

Comment: Even though I sped up the formatting process, it may not make a dent in your overall performance, relatively speaking.  The best thing to do is simply to write your program as you see fit, and then run something like `Java Microbenchmark Harness` to zero in on where to best focus focus your optimization efforts.2/2.

Comment: @WJS...There is a computational cost of converting an array of numbers such as 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11 to output in the format of 2² · 3² · 5⁴.  I was merely seeking a more efficient way than what I have devised.  When dealing with very large composites, it can make a big difference...when compared to just outputing  2 2 3 3 5 5 5 5 11.  I will try to implement the improvements you have suggested...I do have a little difficulty in understanding your code, but I will study it.  All I want is just to get the array of primes sorting to the 2² · 3² · 5⁴ format with less computational cost.  Thats all.

Comment: BTW, since your exponents will all be >= 1 you can remove the code dealing with the sign.

Comment: @WJS....yes, they will all be positive integers.  I will remove the code you suggested.  Thanks again for the time and trouble..